# Continous Rotation Servo not changing directions

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, continuous-servo

I have coded a robot to be controlled by a ps3 Controller. I am using continous rotation servos but unfortunately I can not figure out how to get them to change direction. My input for my if statements is correct, but for some reason even if the input from the PS3 controller shows to do the reverse direction, the continuous rotation servo still rotates forward.

Here is my Code:

```
  #include <PS3BT.h>
  #include <usbhub.h>

  // Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
  #ifdef dobogusinclude
  #include <spi4teensy3.h>
  #endif
  #include <SPI.h>

  #include <Servo.h>


  USB Usb;
  //USBHub Hub1(&Usb); // Some dongles have a hub inside

  BTD Btd(&Usb); // You have to create the Bluetooth Dongle instance like so
  /* You can create the instance of the class in two ways */
  PS3BT PS3(&Btd); // This will just create the instance
  //PS3BT PS3(&Btd, 0x00, 0x15, 0x83, 0x3D, 0x0A, 0x57); // This will also store the bluetooth address - this can be obtained from the dongle when running the sketch

  bool printTemperature, printAngle;

  // identifying servos
  Servo LeftServo;
  Servo RightServo;


  void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    #if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
    while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
  #endif
    if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
      Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
      while (1); //halt
     }
    Serial.print(F("\r\nPS3 Bluetooth Library Started"));

  // Attaching Pins to Servos
    LeftServo.attach(2);
    RightServo.attach(3);

  }
  void loop() {
    Usb.Task();

    if (PS3.PS3Connected || PS3.PS3NavigationConnected) {
    if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) < 117){
Serial.print(F("\tLeftHatY: "));
Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
  LeftServo.attach(2);
LeftServo.write(180);

}
else if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) > 140) {
     Serial.print(F("\tLeftHatY: "));
Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
    LeftServo.attach(2);
  LeftServo.write(0);
  }
else {
LeftServo.detach();
   }
   }
    }
```

Comment: I added the rest of my code, I thought to only post the relevant section but this has changed.

Comment: forget about your code for now ... write a simple program that runs the motor in one direction for two seconds, stops the motor,  then runs the motor in the opposite direction

Comment: please, format your code properly ... it is a mess that is difficult to read

Comment: What are the specific servos that you’re using?

Comment: Are you able to add a schematic showing how you’re connecting and powering the servos?

Comment: Is this related to your other question yesterday? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/91238/different-code-needed-for-continuous-rotation-servo

Answer (score 0):

im new in Arduino projects but i think this might work, try changing some things in your else sttement, you should try and change this

```
LeftServo.attach(2);
  LeftServo.write(0);
```

Try changing it to this

```
LeftServo.attach(2);
  LeftServo.write(180*(-1));
// or, LeftServo.write(-180);
/* if you use (180*(-1), the servo might go the opposite direction continuously until 
(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) is less than 117 */
```